# How to update state within a custom tab bar with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a custom TabBar which navigates only forward with a button click.
im using an enum to manage the state and couple of class objects to manage items for Tabs.

What result I expected
[image: Expected result]

VS

What result I've got

[image: What result I've got]

The code I worked out is as follows. I am still trying to figure out a way of managing the expected outcome with my code implementation. if anyone can help out will be amazing.

**Object classes**

```
class CategoryModel {
  final String? title;
  final eCategory category;
  // final eCategoryState? catState;

  CategoryModel({this.title, required this.category});
}

class CategoryStateModel {
  final CategoryModel? tItem;
  late eTabState? tState;

  CategoryStateModel({this.tItem, this.tState});
}
```

**The code portion**

```
class _ContributeTabScreenState extends State<ContributeTabScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  eButtonState _submitBtnState = eButtonState.bActive;
  eButtonState _continueBtnState = eButtonState.bActive;
  int pageNo = 0;
  TabController? _tabController;
  late List<eTabState>? _tabState = [];
  late List<CategoryModel>? _categoryModelList = [];
  late List<Tab>? _tabList = [];
  late List<CategoryStateModel>? _catStateList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _categoryModelList = widget.catList;
    _assignTabs();
    _tabController = new TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: _categoryModelList!.length, //3,
    );
    super.initState();
    // print(_categoryModelList![0].title.toString());
  }

  List<Tab> _assignTabs() {
    for (var item = 0; item < _categoryModelList!.length; item++) {
      //
      if (item != 0) {
        for (var t in _categoryModelList!) {
          _catStateList!.add(
              new CategoryStateModel(tItem: t, tState: eTabState.tUnSelected));
        }
      } else {
        for (var t in _categoryModelList!) {
          _catStateList!.add(
              new CategoryStateModel(tItem: t, tState: eTabState.tSelected));
        }
      }
      //
      _tabList!.add(
        new Tab(
          child: _tabItem(_catStateList![item]),
          // child: _tabItem(_categoryModelList![item]),
        ),
      );
    }
    return _tabList!;
  }

  void _goBack() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

//the onPressed call back I manage the forward move of a tabbar item + tabview 
  void forwardTabPage() {
    if (pageNo >= 0 && pageNo < _categoryModelList!.length) {
      setState(() {
        // });
        // setState(() {
        pageNo = pageNo + 1;
        // _catStateList![pageNo - 1].tState = eTabState.tCompleted;
        // _tabState![pageNo - 1] = _catStateList![pageNo - 1].tState!;
      });
      _tabController!.animateTo(pageNo);
    }
  }

...rest of the code


//the Tabbar item 
_tabItem(CategoryStateModel item) => Container(
        width: 140.0,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              item.tItem!.title!,
              style: tBody4.copyWith(color: CustomColors.mDarkBlue),
            ),
            item.tState == _catStateList![pageNo].tState //eTabState.tCompleted
                ? SizedBox(
                    width: 8.0,
                  )
                : SizedBox(
                    width: 0.0,
                  ),
            item.tState == _catStateList![pageNo].tState //eTabState.tCompleted
                ? CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 12.0,
                    backgroundColor: CustomColors.green600,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.check_outlined,
                      size: 20.0,
                    ),
                  )
                : SizedBox(
                    width: 0.0,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  continueBtn() => ButtonWidget(
        btnColor: CustomColors.green600,
        borderColor: CustomColors.green600,
        textColor: CustomColors.mWhite,
        text: "Continue",
        eButtonType: eButtonType.bText,
        eButtonState: _continueBtnState,
        onPressed: () {
          forwardTabPage();
          // _tabState = eTabState.tCompleted;
        },
      );

  submitBtn() => ButtonWidget(
        btnColor: CustomColors.green600,
        borderColor: CustomColors.green600,
        textColor: CustomColors.mWhite,
        text: "Submit",
        eButtonType: eButtonType.bText,
        eButtonState: _submitBtnState,
        onPressed: () {},
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _categoryModelList!.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 60.0,
          leadingWidth: 100.0,
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _goBack,
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 16.0,
                  ),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: CustomColors.grey700,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      "Back",
                      style: tButtonSmall,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0.0,
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
            child: IgnorePointer(
              child: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  isScrollable: false,
                  enableFeedback: false,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  indicator:
                      // _tabState == eTabState.tSelected
                      //     ?
                      BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                    color: CustomColors.green300,
                    border: Border.all(color: CustomColors.mGreen, width: 2),
                  ),
                  tabs: _tabList!
               
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Container(
                color: CustomColors.grey600.withOpacity(0.2),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Home Tab View"),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text("Map Tab View"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        persistentFooterButtons: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            // height: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: (_categoryModelList!.length == 1 ||
                    pageNo == _categoryModelList!.length - 1)
                ? submitBtn()
                : continueBtn(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**enum classes**

```dart
enum eCategoryState {
  cSelected,
  cUnSelected,
  cEnded,
}

enum eTabState {
  tSelected,
  tUnSelected,
  tCompleted,
}

enum eCategory {
  cAccess,
  cAmenities,
}
```

Comment: Can you include full code-snippet to test it out?

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: Sorry bro, it is still missing `ButtonWidget`,  `CustomColors`..., can run provide  [dartPad](dartpad.dev) link

Comment: Button widget is a custom class. it is there to just invoke onPressed method. you can replace it with a material button if you like. the call back method im passing to onPressed is "forwardTabPage()"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you mean or not. but try this. `TabBar` has a `isScrollable` property. set it to `true`

Comment: thank you for the comment. but setting that to true does not change anything